# Is there a Monotouch port available for the C# Facebook Sdk?

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin.ios, facebook-c#-sdk

Monotouch requires a special build for the Iphone/Ipad. Is there a DLL available?
Or source code?

thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short Answer -- Yes!

I have created a simple port of the C# Facebook SDK for MonoTouch. It's not official by any means but it required me massaging some of the bits from Mono's MCS to make it compatible. It also plays nice with MonoTouch's AOT (Ahead of Time) compilation scheme.

### Usage

Unfortunately you don't get 'dynamic' or 'ExpandoObject' in MonoTouch see my bit about AOT compilation ^. So basically you are required to use the .NET 3.5 APIs or as I like to call it "magic strings ftw!" From the SDK docs:

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
var me = (IDictionary<string,object>)client.Get("me");
string firstName = (string)me["first_name"];
string lastName = (string)me["last_name"];
string email = (string)me["email"];
```

### Go Git It!

https://github.com/anujb/MonoMobile.Facebook

Feel free to contribute. I can imagine there are tons of helpers that can be created and made available to aid iOS developers using MonoTouch decrease the friction of developing these apps. There are quite a few base constructs that are common for most iOS UI requirements

Thanks.

Anuj

Comment: Is there a sample code available? it looks different to the windows library.

Answer (score 1):

There is no port but there are bindings to the obj-c Facebook SDK available. I would use this since it is running against the supported FB SDK.

https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/monotouch-facebook

Comment: Ive tried this already, but keep getting error messages back - "The operation couldn?t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)", the windows C# library works better, but needs a bit of work.

Comment: At what point in your project would you get this error? And what was the stack trace and/or crash report? monotouch-facebook has been pretty solid for me.

Answer (score 0):

currently there is no official port of Facebook C# SDK for monotouch or monodroid although it has been something we really want to have.

as for now you can trak this feature at http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/5773

Answer (score 0):

There is a component in the Xamarin Component store that's called Facebook SDK, available here: http://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk/

It's created from the same organization (outercurve) that created the C# SDK.